# Program isn't running

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a code but it's not working and I can't seem to find the errors if there are any

```
def question3():
x= input("Enter the first value:")
y= input("Enter the second value:")
z= input("Enter the third value:")
if x==y==z:
    print("All three inputs have equal values" + x)
elif x==y:
    print("x and y have equal values" + x)
elif x==z:
    print("x and z have equal values" + x)
elif y==z:
     print("y and z have equal values" + y)
else:
    print("All three inputs have different values")
```

Comment: do you call the function `question3()`?

Comment: With the correct indentantion, it runs for me. Do you use Python3?

Comment: Formatting is off

Comment: It's indented wrong. Since you haven't specified what error you're getting, presumably that's the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

```
def question3():
    x= input("Enter the first value:")
    y= input("Enter the second value:")
    z= input("Enter the third value:")
    if x==y==z:
        print("All three inputs have equal values" + x)
    elif x==y:
        print("x and y have equal values" + x)
    elif x==z:
        print("x and z have equal values" + x)
    elif y==z:
         print("y and z have equal values" + y)
    else:
        print("All three inputs have different values")
    return
```